# Install Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm completely new to node.js. By reading the documentation and tutorials, I managed to download and install node.js on my windows.

How do I test it and make it work?

The file test.js is saved in the same directory as node.exe and contains:

```
console.log('Hello World');
```

Openning the command-line I typed:

```
$ node test.js
```

But nothing hapenns, just:

```
...
```

Comment: Did you use the node command-line or the general windows command-line?

Comment: I believe that is linux

Comment: @Sirko: node command-line

Comment: 1. You must be using Node.js command prompt. 2.Navigate to path having test.js using `cd` command 3. run `node test.js`.

Comment: @SmartLemon, I think windows since it is mentioned above "I managed to download and install node.js on my windows."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

![enter image description here][1]I have run it in nodejs shell and it is simply working

```
> console.log('Hello World');  
  Hello World  
  undefined  
>
```

Also I opened nodejs command prompt not default command prompt of windows and then

```
 node path_to_file
```

it is working...  same output

Comment: Yes, that also works for me. The problem is loading a js file from the command-line

Comment: yes please open node js command prompt and then try it not default command prompt of windows

Comment: what is your node version? is it installed properly?

Comment: I'm using v0.10.18. I've just downloaded and installed it from nodejs.org

Comment: where do you save your `js `file look at my uploaded picture I saved the js file in Desktop and then through command line I ran it by proper path

Comment: I got it, looking at your picture above, I found out I have to use Node.js command prompt and not node.exe command prompt. I have no idea why there are 2 command prompts. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are typing `node test.js` in the Node REPL not the command line. The `...` is indicating that you haven't reached the end of a valid statement yet (because you are writing shell and not JavaScript).

Run a command line with your terminal emulator of choice (probably Windows Powershell if you are using Windows).

Comment: Using Windows Powershell I get "The term $ is not recognized ...". test.js in the same directory

Comment: `$` is the representation of the command prompt, not something that you type yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Run the Node REPL by executing node via the command-line without any arguments. The reason you're not getting the expected results is probably because you're running `node.exe` directly. Since you're using windows, start up `CMD` and run `node.exe` from there. Once you have the REPL running, try `node test.js` again, and this time it will work.